# Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'ngs-code-editor'

Tags: angular

I have imported the following lines in angular module and also imported.but still getting following error
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'ngs-code-editor'.

1. If 'ngs-code-editor' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngs-code-editor' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

import { CodeEditorModule } from '@ngstack/code-editor';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

imports: [CodeEditorModule.forRoot()  ,FormsModule
],

```
  <ngs-code-editor style="height:90%;width:100%"
  theme="vs-light" 
  
  [(value)]="code"
  language="typescript"
 
  [options]="options"
  (valueChanged)="onrqCodeChanged($event)">
</ngs-code-editor>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred because Angular couldn't find the `CodeEditorModule`.

For example, if the `CodeEditorModule.forRoot()` is imported in your `component.module.ts`, make sure you import `ComponentModule` within your `AppModule`.

Comment: Yes, i imported the component in the app module                                                            import { CodeEditorModule } from '@ngstack/code-editor';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';   @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ContextMenuModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    NgJsonEditorModule,
    HttpClientModule ,
    CodeEditorModule.forRoot()  ,FormsModule,
    NgxCSVtoJSONModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

Answer (score 0):

value is no longer an attribute in the new version.

You have to use d codeModel instead.

### In your .html:

```html
<ngs-code-editor [theme]="theme"
                 [codeModel]="codeModel" 
                 [options]="options"
                 (valueChanged)="onCodeChanged($event)">
</ngs-code-editor>
```

### in your .ts

```js
codeModel: CodeModel = {
    language: 'json',
    uri: 'main.json',
    value: '{}',
};
```